# How do I cancel Google voice?

Tags: google-voice

I would like to cancel my account so that it doesn't exist any longer. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=4cb2fcba55744b7c&hl=en) on the Google Voice forums.

> Uncheck all your phones and turn on Do
>   Not Disturb.

Comment: And you should know that at this time, google voice does not have a "cancel" option. That is why this answer is the best you can do.

Comment: I have discovered that after having done this for quite some time (a year?), the number gets reclaimed by google.